# Setting Attr to closest <a> using src img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know it's a really basic question. I'm trying to get the "src" as a variable and set it to the closest  in "href".

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vitorboccio/EUpRg/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="instafeed">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <img src="http://scontent-a.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/915462_665185033531202_40962267_s.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <img src="http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xpf1/t51.2885-15/10299842_1424124577859264_383342252_s.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

js:

```
function changeURL () {
    //var srcImg = this.src;
    var srcImg = $(this).attr("src");
    console.log(srcImg);
    $("#instafeed").closest('a').attr('href', srcImg);
}

$("#instafeed").on('click', 'img', function () {
    changeURL();        
});
```

thanks

Comment: What's this `$("#instafeed").closest('a').attr('href', srcImg);` supposed to do?

Comment: Are you going to find the closest <a> from <img>?

Comment: The `$(this)` in your `changeURL` function points to `window`. You need to send a reference of the element to that function.

Comment: Out of interest - why are you doing this on click rather than document ready?

Comment: @putvande NB: the canonical way of doing that is to simply pass `changeURL` directly to `.on` at which point jQuery will automatically do the right thing - not passing that reference as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the anonymous function wrapping the call to `changeURL` - it's breaking the automatic behaviour of jQuery that sets `this` in the called function to be the clicked element:

```
$('#instafeed').on('click', 'img', changeURL);
```

You also then need to refer to that clicked element inside the handler, instead of `#instafeed`:

```
function changeURL() {
    $(this).closest('a').prop('href', this.src);
 };
```

NB: I've changed `$(this).attr('src')` to just `this.src`.  The only difference is that the latter will be a fully qualified absolute URL, whereas the former might be relative.  I've also used `.prop` instead of `.attr` to *set* the property, since that's the more idiomatic way of changing an element's properties since jQuery 1.6

Also, if the `<a>` element is always the direct ancestor the optimal solution would be this, eliminating all five calls to jQuery in your original code with direct DOM manipulation:

```
function changeURL() {
    this.parentNode.href = this.src;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

changeURL receives no parameter and has no way to guess what image are you addressing.

Try this

```
function changeURL (imgElement) {
    var srcImg = imgElement.attr("src");
    console.log(srcImg);
    imgElement.closest('a').attr('href', srcImg);
}

$("#instafeed").on('click', 'img', function () {
    changeURL(jQuery(this));        
});
```

Comment: I think that still won't work as `closest` travels up in the DOM, not down.

Comment: Right! @putvande, fixed

Comment: Ok, worked, thx a lot. I'll accept as right answer in 3 minutes :) ty

Comment: @vbotio This is really not that good an answer - there is _absolutely no need_ for that extra `function`.  jQuery event handlers should use `this` (not passed parameters) just like your own code did.  The main mistake you made was the extra function wrapper, which this answer perpetuates.

Comment: I tried to show the OP how he should change what he already had done for it to work. Doesn't the site encourage people to show what they tried already? What good would it be if the answers changed the whole structure of their code?

Comment: @amenadiel all the OP had to do was remove the extraneous anonymous function wrapper and then fix `$('#instafeed')` to `$(this)`.  The structure of his code is otherwise unchanged, and the resulting code is more idiomatic than passing the element as a parameter (or worse still, as a jQuery object, as your code does - actually a far more fundamental change).

Comment: Yup, you might be right. Altought I insist I was trying to preserve the structure for the OP to follow it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

After viewing your codes, I think you are trying to get the image src and set it to href in the closest `<a>` tag. If so, find the closest `<a>` from the `<img>`

```
function changeURL () {
    var srcImg = $(this).attr("src");
    console.log(srcImg);
    $(this).closest('a').attr('href', srcImg); 
    // the $(this) is referring to <img>
}

$("#instafeed").on('click', 'img', changeURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the JS to this:

```
function changeURL () {
  var srcImg = $(this).attr("src");
  console.log(srcImg);
  $(this).closest('a').attr('href', srcImg);
}

$("#instafeed").on('click', 'img', changeURL);
```

- Removed anonymous function around `changeURL` binding, now binding directly to `changeURL` method, thus keeping the `this` reference.
- Changed `.closest()` call to be happening on the `img` tag rather than `#instafeed`

http://jsfiddle.net/EUpRg/3/

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
function changeURL (imgElement) {
    var srcImg = imgElement.attr("src");
    console.log(srcImg);

    $("#instafeed").find('a:eq(0)').prop('href', srcImg);
}

$("#instafeed").on('click', 'img', function () {

    changeURL($(this));        
});
[Demo][1]
```